# SoftAssertion specific to test in TestNG

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests, testng

I'm using soft assertion of TestNG, like following code.

```
public class SoftAssertionTest {
    SoftAssert softAssert = new SoftAssert();

    @Test
    public void test1(){
        softAssert.assertEquals(2, 3);
        softAssert.assertEquals(2, 2);
        softAssert.assertEquals(2, 5);
        softAssert.assertAll();
    }

    @Test
    public void test2(){
        softAssert.assertEquals(2, 2);
        softAssert.assertTrue(false);
        softAssert.assertAll();
    }
}
```

But when this test class is run, for `test1` it'll return result like -

```
java.lang.AssertionError: The following asserts failed:
    expected [3] but found [2],
    expected [5] but found [2]
```

which is correct but for `test2`, it returns failures of `test1` and `test2`

```
java.lang.AssertionError: The following asserts failed:
    expected [3] but found [2],
    expected [5] but found [2],
    expected [true] but found [false]
```

Actually, it should return result of only `test2`.

This can be achieved by creating local variable of `SoftAssert` in each test method. But that can be duplicate of code.

Is there any way we can use same object and in each test method clear test failure results from that object so that in new test method, it'll capture only failures related to that method.

Answer (score 2):

`SoftAssert` class has only one public method in it's source - `assertAll()`.
So it's a common practice to create a new instance of `SoftAssert` for every test.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create SoftAssert object for each test case rather than having class variable. So your code should look like below:

```
public class SoftAssertionTest {


    @Test
    public void test1(){
        SoftAssert softAssert = new SoftAssert();
        softAssert.assertEquals(2, 3);
        softAssert.assertEquals(2, 2);
        softAssert.assertEquals(2, 5);
        softAssert.assertAll();
    }

    @Test
    public void test2(){
        SoftAssert softAssert = new SoftAssert();
        softAssert.assertEquals(2, 2);
        softAssert.assertTrue(false);
        softAssert.assertAll();
    }
}
```

If you are using selenium with TestNG, you should use [TesNG's qaf extension](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/wiki/3rd-party-extensions#frameworks) which provides in-built support for [assertion and verification](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/assertion_verification.html) reporting each assertion/verification in the [reports](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/qaf_reporting.html#test-details) whether it passed or failed.

With QAF your example may look like below:

```
import static com.qmetry.qaf.automation.util.Validator.verifyThat;
import static com.qmetry.qaf.automation.util.Validator.verifyTrue;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo;

public class SoftAssertionTest {

    @Test
    public void test1(){
       verifyThat(2, equalTo(3));
       verifyThat(2, equalTo(2));
       verifyThat("just for fun",2, equalTo(5));
    }

    @Test
    public void test2(){
        verifyThat(2, equalTo(2));
        verifyTrue(false,"failure message","success message");
    }
}
```

You will get report like below:

```
test1
Check Points:   


Expected: <3>
     Actual: was <2>


Expected: <2>
     Actual: was <2>

just for fun
Expected: <5>
     Actual: was <2>


test2
Check Points:   

just for fun
Expected: <2>
     Actual: was <2>

failure message
```

You will see red and green mark in html report with each checkpoint.[image: test result]  Observe that it also provides you the success details. In case of browser/mobile qaf will attach screen shot with each checkpoint.